# Multithreading Perl script and crontab/init script

Tags: multithreading, perl, cron

I have an issue with a `Perl` script using thread.

It works fine when I launch it manually but when I launch it using crontab I have this feedback:

Perl exited with active threads:

```
    0 running and unjoined
    1 finished and unjoined
    0 running and detached
```

The `PATH` variable and `SHELL` variable are correct on the crontad.

I try to make a init script (to launch as a service) and same error:

> Feb 24 08:04:48 SERVER kernel: perl[103293]: segfault at 4a8 ip
>   00007f6cfd075dd9 sp 00007fffb93437c0 error 4 in
>   libperl.so[7f6cfcfdf000+183000] Feb 24 08:04:49 SERVER
>   test_ping[102238]: Perl exited with active threads: Feb 24 08:04:49
>   SERVER test_ping[102238]: 0 running and unjoined Feb 24 08:04:49
>   SERVER test_ping[102238]: 1 finished and unjoined Feb 24 08:04:49
>   SERVER test_ping[102238]: 0 running and detached

So I have also tried to modified the perl with:

```
for my $thread (threads->list) {                                                                                                                
$thread->join();                                                                               
}
```

Instead of

```
for my $thread (threads->list) {                                                                                                                
$thread->detach();                                                                               
}
```

And after this modification when I launch manually the script, this one seems to be stuck/freezing.

So to resume this is all my check:

1. Executed manually it work
2. Via crontab it doesn't work, check of PATH variable and SHELL
   variable are ok
3. Via init script, doesn't work
4. Try to modify the perl script to join all thread but it the script
   is freezing after that.

Anyone has a suggestion ? Something else to check/do ?

Thk

```
 use lib '/usr/local/perf/lib';
use lib '/usr/share/perl5';
use threads;
use Thread::Queue;
use SNMP::Persist qw(&define_oid &start_persister &define_subtree);
use Schedule::ByClock;
use Time::HiRes qw( usleep ualarm gettimeofday tv_interval );

use strict;
#use warnings;
use constant DEBUG => 0;
use constant DEBUG2 => 1;

if ($#ARGV + 1 != 2) {
 print "usage: test_ping.pl OUTPUTFILE INPUTFILE \n";
 exit;
}

my $output_file=$ARGV[0];
my $data_file=$ARGV[1];
shift @ARGV;
shift @ARGV;

#start the thread serving answers
start_persister();

#create queue for processing commands
my $q_queue = new Thread::Queue;
my $r_queue = new Thread::Queue;

#create threads for processing queues
for(my $i= 0; $i < $thread_num; $i++) {
        threads->create(\&process) -> detach();
}
        my $datestring=localtime();

        my %subtree;
        my @raw_data;

        my ($q_line, @q_split);
        my ($r_line, @r_split);
        my $index=0;

        # open file to get data
        open(DAT, $data_file) || die("Could not open file!");
        @raw_data=<DAT>;
        close(DAT);

        # enqueue all lines to be process by threads
        foreach $q_line (@raw_data) {
                chomp($q_line);
                $q_line =~ s/^\s+//;
                $q_line =~ s/\s+$//;
                next if ($q_line =~ /^#.*/);
                next if ($q_line eq "");
                next if ($q_line =~ /^\|/);

                @q_split=split(/\|/,$q_line);
                next if (!($q_split[0] eq "icmp" || $q_split[0] eq "tcp" || $q_split[0] eq "ldap" || $q_split[0] eq "dig" ));

                $q_queue->enqueue(++$index ."|". $q_line);
        }

        while ($index != 0 && ($r_line = $r_queue->dequeue)) {

                open(my $fh, '>>', $output_file) or die "Could not open file '$output_file' $!";
                print $fh $datestring."|";
                print $fh $r_line."\n";
                close $fh;
                @r_split=split(/\|/,$r_line);
                $index--;
        }

        for my $thread (threads->list) {                                                                                                                
            $thread->detach();                                                                               
    }
```

Below the process fonction:

```
sub process {
    # my @hotefqdn = split(/\./, `hostname`);
    # my $hote=$hotefqdn[0];
    my ($q_line,@q_split,$q_index,$q_query);
    my ($q_module,$q_type,$q_name,$q_host,$q_port,$q_ssl,$q_send,$q_expect,$q_quit);
    my ($q_lookup,$q_record);
    my ($q_base_dn,$q_attr,$q_binddn,$q_password,$q_warn_time,$q_crit_time,$q_timeout);
    my ($r_tab);

    while ($q_line = $q_queue->dequeue) { 

            @q_split=split(/\|/,$q_line);

            $q_index=$q_split[0];
            $q_module=$q_split[1];

            if ($q_module eq "icmp") {
                    $q_type=$q_split[2];
                    $q_name=$q_split[3];
                    $q_host=$q_split[4];
                    $q_query="$q_host (ping)";
                    print "query=$q_query\n" if(DEBUG);
                    $r_tab=icmp_query($q_host);
            }
            elsif ($q_module eq "tcp") {
                    $q_type=$q_split[2];
                    $q_name=$q_split[3];
                    $q_query="$q_host ($q_type:$q_port)";
                    print "query=$q_query\n" if(DEBUG);
                    $r_tab=tcp_query($q_host,$q_port,$q_ssl,$q_send,$q_expect,$q_quit);
            }
            elsif ($q_module eq "ldap") {
                    $q_type=$q_split[2];
                    $q_name=$q_split[3];
                    print "query=$q_query\n" if(DEBUG);
                    $r_tab=ldap_query($q_host,$q_base_dn,$q_port,$q_attr,$q_binddn,$q_password,$q_warn_time,$q_crit_time,$q_timeout);
            }
            elsif ($q_module eq "dig") {
                    $q_type=$q_split[2];
                    $q_name=$q_split[3];
                    $q_query="$q_lookup($q_record) @".$q_host;
                    print "query=$q_query\n" if(DEBUG);
                    $r_tab=dig_query($q_host,$q_port,$q_lookup,$q_record,$q_expect);
            }

            $r_queue->enqueue($q_index."|".$q_name."|".$q_type."|".$q_query."|".$r_tab->{'min'}."|".$r_tab->{'med'}."|".$r_tab->{'avg'}."|".$r_tab->{'max'}."|".$r_tab->{'dev'}."|".$r_tab->{'loss'}."|".$r_tab->{'err'});
    }
```

}

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could come up with a minimal, compilable code snippet that reproduces the problem you're having.

Comment: And that's why I asked for a _minimal snippet_ that still reproduces the problem. Because the problem likely has something to do with the code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't detach your threads. When you do, you can't wait for them to finish.

```
for (my $i= 0; $i < $thread_num; $i++) {
    threads->create(\&process) -> detach();
}

...

for my $thread (threads->list) {
    $thread->detach();
}
```

should be

```
for (1..$thread_num) {
    threads->create(\&process);
}

...

... Tell the threads to finish up ...

for my $thread (threads->list) {
    $thread->join();
}
```

---

Now on the question: Why don't your threads finish? Well, you never tell them to exit, so they never do! You need to ask to them to exit, and that can be achieved by adding the following:

```
$q_queue->end();
```

---

What follows is what you get after you apply the above fixes. I've also moved all thread-related code out of `process`, since it doesn't belong there. Finally, I removed the reliance on `$index` by moving the output code into its own thread.

```
sub process {
   my ($q_line) = @_;
   ...
   return join("|", $q_index, $q_name, $q_type, $q_query, @$r_tab{qw( min med avg max dev loss err )});
}

my $request_q  = Thread::Queue->new();
my $response_q = Thread::Queue->new();

my @worker_threads;
for (1..$thread_num) {
   push @worker_threads, async {
      while (defined( my $request = $request_q->dequeue() )) {
         $response_q->enqueue( process($request) );
      }
   };
}

my $output_thread = do {
   my $datestring = localtime();

   open(my $fh, '>', $output_file)
      or die("Can't create file \"$output_file\": $!\n");

   async {
      while (defined( my $response = $response_q->dequeue() )) {
         print($fh "$datestring|$response\n");
      }
   }
};

{    
   my %protos = map { $_ => 1 } qw( icmp tcp ldap dig );

   open(my $fh, '<', $data_file)
      or die("Can't open file \"$data_file\": $!\n");

   my $index = 0;
   while (<$fh>) {
      s/^\s+//;
      s/\s+\z//;
      next if $_ eq "" || /^#/;

      my ($proto) = split /\|/;
      next if !$protos{$proto};

      $request_q->enqueue(++$index ."|". $_);
   }
}

$request_q->end();
$_->join() for @worker_threads;

$response_q->end();
$output_threads->join();
```

Comment: I already do this modification and it's worse. The script doesn't work when I launch it manually.

[root@SERVER]# ./test_ping.sh
<stuck here, it doesnt give me access to the prompt again>

Comment: @elbrabra94, Again, you're asking why `process` doesn't return, but you didn't show `process`. I can only fix the problems you didn't ask about.

Comment: Ho sorry I a add the process function on my main post

Comment: So I was right. You never told your threads to exit, so it's just a question of doing so as I detailed.

Comment: Ouch you have changed a lot of thing.

Comment: Yeah, I did lots of cleaning. (I just improved the explanation of these changes a bit.) Those changes aren't necessary, but it's far cleaner code.